# AdaCore : importing packages e.g.'Display'

Tags: ada

can someone advise on how to import the 'Display' packages to GPS community edition?
[YouTube: AdaCore Lesson#2]https://youtube.com/watch?v=3jtOFle5K_c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are part of the Game_Support library found [here](https://github.com/AdaCore/labs-material).

Comment: understanding from Github repo, that we need to save all the supporting files to the dir, my concern is how to know what are the current support libraries there for Ada? is there a list that I could refer to?

Comment: @ThiwankaJ  Not sure I understand your question, but the project file (.gpr) usually lists all the library dependencies.  It will "with XXXX;" at the top.  Though you may then have to go check XXXX.gpr as well and see if it has any dependencies and so on.

Comment: Hi Jere, thanks for your comment. I appreciate it.  My question is in general, not related to the one I asked earlier.  I want to know the freely available packages list on Ada. e.g. Display, are you aware of a reference like that I referred to?

Comment: @ThiwankaJ you can check both https://github.com/ohenley/awesome-ada and https://www.adaic.org/ada-resources/tools-libraries/

Comment: Thanks, Jere, that answers my question. However, I noticed that the package is a different term in the Ada world.  I was after the libraries.